# Pyinstaller .exe not working (unhandled exception in script)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This is the traceback I got when the .exe opened

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>


   x1 = int(input("Insira primeiro valor de x:"))

RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

I don´t understand why it can´t load an input

I used pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py

And already moved the .exe into the same folder as the code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x1 = int(input("Insira primeiro valor de x:"))
x2 = int(input("Insira segundo valor de x:"))
x3 = int(input("Insira terceiro valor de x:"))
x4 = int(input("Insira quarto valor de x:"))

y1 = int(input("Insira primeiro valor de y:"))
y2 = int(input("Insira segundo valor de y:"))
y3 = int(input("Insira terceiro valor de y:"))
y4 = int(input("Insira quarto valor de y:"))

aceleracao_x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
forca_y = [y1, y2, y3, y4]

plt.plot(aceleracao_x, forca_y, color = 'b')
color = ['black']
plt.scatter(aceleracao_x, forca_y, c = color)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Vinicius Andrade Trento')


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try generating exe by `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`